# Prevent multipe eventhandler execution in backbon subview

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view created (list container) in Backbone which should contain multiple view items (sections) with the handling for some events. The problem in this scenario is that event is executed as often as the subview item was placed inside the container.

I know that I can prevent this effect if I put the closeSection method into Container view but I think it's the wrong place there with focus on a full working view.

What is the best solution to solve this problem in a Backbone.js context?

EXAMPLE:

```
// The Container View (simplified)
var Container = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:$('#someDivContainer'),

  render:function(){
    $(this.el).html('<div id="head"></div><div id="sections"></div>');
    return this;
  }
});


// The subview (simplified)
var subView = backbone.View.extend({
  template:_template('<div><div class="scthd"><a class="op_cl">x</a></div><div><%- content %></div></div>');
  events:{
    'click a.op_cl':'closeSection'
  },

  initialize:function(){
    this.setElement($('#sections');
  },

  closeSection:function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('event was triggered');
  },


  render:function(){
     $(this.el).append(this.template({content:'Test ' + i});
     return this;
  }
}); 

var oContainer = new Container();
    oContainer.render().el;


 // These produces a ten time event execution by a click on one a.op_cl item
 for(var i=0; i<10; i+=1){
   var oSubView = new subView();
       oSubView.render().el;
 }
```

The "final" output looks like the following example:

```
<!-- The HTMl of the first view -->
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="sections">
  <div>
    <div class="scthd">
      <a class="op_cl">x</a>
    </div>
    <div>Test 0</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="scthd">
      <a class="op_cl">x</a>
    </div>
    <div>Test 1</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="scthd">
      <a class="op_cl">x</a>
    </div>
    <div>Test 2</div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="scthd">
      <a class="op_cl">x</a>
    </div>
    <div>Test n</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

THX in advance.

Comment: To me the question is not really clear. Some code is missing. What is the result? The event is fired multiple times?

Comment: @namero999 So, I think now it's more clear to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what your problem is you need to first understand that in backbone.js when you declare an event hash those events are delegated to the root `el` of the view. What's happening in your case is that since all of your sub-views are using the same `#sections` element their events are being bound to the same element.

I'm not sure why you have them set to the same element so depending on what you are trying to do, you can either leave out the `this.setElement($('#sections'));` and have the container view append the sub-views or use some other method to append the sub-views. As far as communicating events to the container view you can just have the events declared in the container view.

Comment: It's bcause I have a Sidebar with multiple elements which are all different to the others without the wrapper around. So I thougt its the best to define a wiew for That wrapper.

Comment: OK made a change on the point of view. But for my question this is the right answear

Comment: @Bernhard I disagree that the right approach is to have the 'close' event declared in the container view. Modularity breaks. You don't 'close' the container, you 'close' the subview. Then the event should be there. You'll end up making the same error twice imho.

Comment: @namero999 I would say it depends on the relationship of the sub-views to the container view, if they are children of it (As in this case) I don't think it's to much of an issue to have *their* container to close them. An alternative option would be to have the sub-view trigger an event and the container view subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you set up your views is conceptually wrong (at least in Backbone land) at it yelds to those results. The main error here is having all your subviews share a single common root element. This is the really bad line:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.setElement($('#sections'));
}
```

This is conceptually wrong because you are assigning responsibilities the other way around. Instead of having a root `Sidebar` view that will build itself with all the needed subviews, you have the subviews attach themselves to the `Sidebar`.

As Jack correctly said in his answer, this has also problems regarding event handling. When you say something like:

```
events: {
    'click a.op_cl': 'closeSection'
}
```

you are attaching a single click event listener to your view's root element, that when fired, will first check if the target matches the selector and if yes will execute your callback. In this case, you are attaching 10 event listener to the same element (`#section`) and when you click on a link, each of those will match and fire.

You should change your subview as

```
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    template: _template('<div class="scthd"><a class="op_cl">x</a></div><div><%- content %></div>'),

    events: {
        'click a.op_cl': 'closeSection'
    },

    closeSection: function(event) {
        console.log('event was triggered');
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).append(this.template({content:'Test ' + i});
        return this;
    }

});
```

And then attach those `SubView` instances to the `Sidebar`, from the `Sidebar`.